# An error has occured but no error stacktrace

Tags: jhipster

I created a new monolithic standalone jhipster project. I ran *mvnw* afterwards and no errors appeared in the console. However, once I've accessed it in the browser, the "An error has occurred :-(" page appeared, but there are no errors in the logs.

I've already followed the error page's recommendations like updating `node.js`, `bower`, and running `jhipster --force`, but the same error page appears. What's weird about this is that there's no error stacktrace appearing in the console.

Here's the complete console log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jhipster Jasper 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ jhipster-jasper >>> [INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (default-resources) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:copy-resources (docker-resources) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent (pre-unit-tests) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\anthony\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.9\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.9-runtime.jar=destfile=D:\\WORKSPACE\\RND\\jhipster_jasper\\target\\test-results\\coverage\\jacoco\\jacoco.exec -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx256m
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 75 source files to D:\WORKSPACE\RND\jhipster_jasper\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ jhipster-jasper <<< [INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.12.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ jhipster-jasper ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\anthony\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/anthony/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
19:10:44.929 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
19:10:44.933 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
19:10:44.935 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/WORKSPACE/RND/jhipster_jasper/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.12.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2018-04-28 19:10:46.477  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.JhipsterJasperApp     : Starting JhipsterJasperApp on orphidian11 with PID 12852 (D:\WORKSPACE\RND\jhipster_jasper\target\classes started by orphidian11 in D:\WORKSPACE\RND\jhipster_jasper)
2018-04-28 19:10:46.480 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.JhipsterJasperApp     : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.12.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.16.RELEASE
2018-04-28 19:10:46.481  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.JhipsterJasperApp     : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2018-04-28 19:10:46.957 DEBUG 12852 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2018-04-28 19:10:50.557 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.j.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor
2018-04-28 19:10:51.778 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2018-04-28 19:10:51.796 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2018-04-28 19:10:52.182 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Registering JVM gauges
2018-04-28 19:10:52.211 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Monitoring the datasource
2018-04-28 19:10:52.213 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.j.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2018-04-28 19:10:53.570 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
2018-04-28 19:10:53.846  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2018-04-28 19:10:53.848 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Initializing Metrics registries
2018-04-28 19:10:53.855 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Filter
2018-04-28 19:10:53.857 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Servlet
2018-04-28 19:10:53.862 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Initialize H2 console
2018-04-28 19:10:53.864  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2018-04-28 19:10:54.369 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.j.config.DatabaseConfiguration       : Configuring Liquibase
2018-04-28 19:10:54.390  WARN 12852 --- [sper-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2018-04-28 19:10:56.859 DEBUG 12852 --- [sper-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 2465 ms
2018-04-28 19:11:05.124 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2018-04-28 19:11:05.136 DEBUG 12852 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 11 ms
2018-04-28 19:11:06.773  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.JhipsterJasperApp     : Started JhipsterJasperApp in 21.811 seconds (JVM running for 22.663)
2018-04-28 19:11:06.776  INFO 12852 --- [  restartedMain] n.o.jasperjhipster.JhipsterJasperApp     :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'jhipster_jasper' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8080
        External:       http://192.168.56.1:8080
        Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-04-28 19:23:03.930  WARN 12852 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=4m39s68ms329┬╡s271ns).
```

Comment: Do you have `gulp` installed?  Try running `gulp build`.  Is there an error when you generate a project?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks. Found out that it was looking for gulp-rev. Installed it via `npm install --global gulp-rev`. Then had to install bower afterwards.